# Mysql: Need a Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have a mysql table like:

```
id   parent_id   date_created   previous_status   next_status
```

This table shows parent_id has faced a status change on date_created date.
How I can create a view or a simple query to show what was the status of each parent, on each time period. For example:

```
id   parent_id   date_created   previous_status   next_status
1    1           2015-10-11     new               old   
2    1           2015-10-12     old               med
3    1           2015-10-13     med               new   
...
...
...
```

Results in

```
parent_id  status from_date   to_date
1          new    null        2015-10-11
1          old    2015-10-11  2015-10-12
1          med    2015-10-12  2015-10-13
1          new    2015-10-13  null
...
...
...
```

This is a sample db table: [Sample audit table](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ajrnan6d6cvo7mc/audit.sql.zip)

Comment: Wouldn't you just store current status !?!?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the next status is to use a correlated subquery.  Then, the other component to the query is getting the initial status, which suggests `union all`:

```
select distinct pid, previous_status as status, null as from_date, date_created as to_date
from t
union all
select pid, next_status, date_created as from_date,
       (select date_created
        from t t2
        where t2.pid = t.pid and t2.date_created > t.date_created
        order by t2.date_created desc
        limit 1
       ) as to_date
from t;
```

Comment: can you edit your answer with from_date and to_date?

Comment: @HPM . . . Are you sure you are using the condition `t2.pid = t.pid`?  You want to use the parent id there, not the row id.  (`asc` versus `desc` was another error that would not result in `NULL` values)

Comment: I edited the question: I need parent_id  status from_date   to_date

Comment: I guess you need to add this to the first uninon:
`GROUP BY pid HAVING date_created = MIN(date_created)`